# vim: define new command that works only outside c++ comments

Tags: vim

When I am coding in c++, I want vim to expand `(` into `()<++>` and place the cursor in the parenthesis. I do this by putting the following line in one of the files loaded at startup:

```
inoremap (      ()<++><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

However, I would like this binding to be disabled in comments, like

```
// Inline comment where ( shouldn't become ()<++>
```

or

```
/* Comment block where ( shouldn't become ()<++>
*/
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Feel free to post vim questions here also: http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How about using a trigger (e.g. `inoremap (<tab> ...`)? Then it will only expand if you hit tab after the parenthesis. With [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) you can even do more fancy stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would like to keep it as simple as it is (given how often I use it :) ). Moreover I think that the problem is of interest: I am curious about the answer

Answer (score 3):

Install [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/) it already detects the context to not expand anywhere. It also adds a placeholder after the closing brackets. If you directly install [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp), the control statements will also be context aware.

(I must admit your request is quite surprising as nobody seems to use placeholders any more. And yet lh-brackets is the plugin that (re-)introduced this concept (idea stolen from Stephen Riehm's original bracketing macros). Then [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/) used a similar bracketing philosophy, and finally latex-suite did as well. BTW, lh-brackets should be compatible with an installed version of latex-suite)

NB: for the ones that absolutely want to define the mappings themselves, look at the [`Map*Context()` functions](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/plugin/misc_map.vim#L200) from lh-brackets. The first version recognizes comments and string contexts to not expand the *key*. The last version (`Map4TheseContext()`) permits to specify how the key should be expanded for a list of possible contexts.
The idea is to test the context with `synIDattr(synID(line('.'),col('.')-1,1),'name')`, then to interpret possible special character sequences like `<esc>`.